# How to fetch data in array from Database using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

i need one help.I need to fetch data from database and store them in an array using PHP and MySQL. My table structure is given below.

> db_special:

```
id     member_id      subcat_id        image         comment

1       135              3             abc.png         hiii

2       135              3             wsd.png         hello

3       135              4             nbh.png         huuuu

4       120              4             nkj.png        hghghg
```

Here the above is my table structure.I need to fetch data using the `member_id` and `subcat_id` which is given by user and it should be grouped by `member_id` .Here i need the fetched data like below format. suppose user have `member_id=135 and subcat_id=3` then result should like below.

```
data={"member_id":135,"subcat_id":3,"special_image"[{"image":"abc.png","comment":"hiii"},{"image":"wsd.png","comment":"hello"}]}
```

Here i need the query.Please help me.

Comment: just use a where clause, fetch it then create an array with that structure above then json encode

Comment: show us your **try** please.

Comment: `$sql=mysqli_query($connect,"select * from db_special where member_id='".$member_id."' and subcat_id='".$subcat_id."' group by member_id ");
$data[]=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);`.

Answer (score 2):

Just like what I've said in the comments. Query, fetch, create array structure, then encode:

```
// connect
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name', 'username', 'password');
$member_id = 135; // values
$subcat_id = 3;
// statement
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM db_special WHERE member_id = :member_id AND subcat_id = :subcat_id');
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':member_id' => $member_id,
    ':subcat_id' => $subcat_id
));
// initialize container format
$data = array(
    'member_id' => $member_id,
    'subcat_id' => $subcat_id,
    'special_image' => array(), // initialize
);
// fetch values and push into container with format
foreach($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    $data['special_image'][] = array('image' => $row['image'], 'comment' => $row['comment']);
}
// encode
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it will help you.

```
<?php
//Your Query
$sql = "YOUR QUERY"
$result = mysql_query($sql);

//Your Array
$newArray = array();

//Your Array Data
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
  $newArray[] = "\"".$row['COLUMN NAME']."\"";
}
?>
```

Comment: @SyedNoman mysql_* functions have been removed from php 7, please switch to PDO, prepared statements and bound parameters.

Comment: @jedifans yes i know it. Thank you for your feedback.